# Cypress execute API calls outside of the browser

Tags: node.js, cypress

I created functions using axios that will setup the testing data before each test is run. They are located in a FOY.js file

```
const axios = require('axios');

//Get the token needed for Bearer Authorization
async function getJWT() {
    const bearerToken = await axios.post('https://www.example.com', {username: 'user', password: 'test1234'});
    return bearerToken.data.access_token
}

//Get the UserId from the email address.
async function getUserId(emailAddress) {
    var bearerToken = await getJWT();
    const userId = await axios.get('https://example.com/users/search?contains='+emailAddress+'', {'headers':{Authorization: 'Bearer '+bearerToken+''}});
    console.log(userId.data.users[0].id);
    return userId.data.users[0].id
}

//Delete a record for a user
async function TMDeleteFOY (emailAddress) {
    var bearerToken = await getJWT();
    var userId = await getUserId(emailAddress);
    const response = await axios.delete('https://example2.com/'+userId+'/record', {'headers':{Authorization: 'Bearer '+bearerToken+''}});
    return response.status
}
module.exports.TMDeleteFOY = TMDeleteFOY;
module.exports.TMUpdateFOY = TMUpdateFOY;
```

Using cy.task()

```
beforeEach(function() {
    cy.task('TMDeleteFOY', 'example@mail.com');
});
```

plugins/index.js

```
const FOY = require('../resetScripts/talentMine/FOY');

module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('task', {
        'TMDeleteFOY': (emailaddress) => {
         return FOY.TMUpdateFOY(emailaddress);
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: Are those your real URLs? You need `https://www.example.com`, not `https:www.example.com`... I just tested with axios and the latter will not work: https://runkit.com/flotwig/5ca629999486de0012adecd6

Comment: Those are not the real URLs

Comment: Ok. You should know that this code you posted will run in the browser context, not in the Node.js context. To run it in the Node.js context, use [`cy.task()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html).

Comment: @ZachBloomquist. I've made changes for cy.task(), but still can't get it to work. I've never used cy.task() before, can you see if the code looks correct?

Comment: Sure, share your code

Comment: Can you clarify what happens when you run this code? What fails? I have a hunch on what could be wrong, but I need to know what you're experiencing to be sure

Comment: @ZachBloomquist Sorry. I didn't realize that I left out the error.  I get "The task 'TMDeleteFOY' returned undefined. You must return a promise, a value, or null to indicate that the task was handled."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return something from your task code so that Cypress knows what to wait for, to know that your task is finished before running other code.

Check out the [`cy.task()` documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html#Command):

> In the `task` plugin event, the command will fail if undefined is returned. This helps catch typos or cases where the task event is not handled.

To fix this, you just need to modify your task code so that a promise is returned. Right now, you aren't returning anything.

In your `plugins/index.js`:

```js
const FOY = require('../resetScripts/talentMine/FOY');

module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('task', {
        'TMDeleteFOY': (emailaddress) => {
            // CHANGED: return a promise so Cypress can wait for it
            return FOY.TMDeleteFOY(emailaddress);
        }
    })
}
```

In your `FOY.js` file (excluded irrelevant sections for brevity):

```js
// start of your FOY.js...

//Delete a record for a user
async function TMDeleteFOY (emailAddress) {
    var bearerToken = await getJWT();
    var userId = await getUserId(emailAddress);
    // CHANGED: return this promise chain so Cypress can wait for it
    return await axios.delete('https://example2.com/'+userId+'/record', {'headers':{Authorization: 'Bearer '+bearerToken+''}});
}

// end of your FOY.js...
```

Comment: I've added my solution to my original question, but this was what I needed. Thank you